# Automatic screen rotation on lenovo yoga 2 11 maybe using magick-rotation

Tags: lenovo, yoga-2

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the Lenovo Yoga 2 11 of a Friend who wanted to use Linux instead of Windows.
After reading about Ubuntu installation on Yoga 2,
all functions are working perfectly, except the automatic screen rotation.

I tested solutions from links like follow:

https://github.com/kkrizka/autorotate

https://launchpad.net/magick-rotation

But nothing helped.
The owner of the yoga 2, absolutely wants to have the automatic screen rotation.
I could not install the magick-rotation tool, even if i follow the manually install instructions and instructions from topics in forums.

Please could somebody help me to get the magick-rotation tool working, or add the automatic screen rotation otherwise?

Btw. I tried to read out the iio sensor data to write an own bash script that would do that, but the integer values are hard to understand, cause they seem to be very random ...

Comment: Possibly of interest... https://gist.github.com/rubo77/daa262e0229f6e398766